# Printing a line read from a file containing a particular word

Tags: c, pointers, file-io, printf, free

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()

{
  int i, p=0;;
    int c;
    char file_name[100];
    char  search[10];

    printf("Enter the file name:");
    scanf("%s", file_name);
    printf("Search word:");
    scanf("%s", search);

    FILE *f = fopen((strcat(file_name, ".txt")), "rb");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    long pos = ftell(f); 
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    char *bytes = malloc(pos + 1);
    fread(bytes, pos, 1, f);
    bytes[ pos ] = '\0'; 

/*search*/

    if (strstr(bytes, search) != NULL){
        printf("found\n");
        p = 1;}
    else{
        printf("Not found\n");

        p=0;}

    free(bytes);

   char *found = strstr( bytes, search );
   if ( found != NULL )
   {
    char *lineStart;
    for(lineStart = strchr(bytes, '\n');  !strcmp(lineStart,"\n"); 
        lineStart = strchr(lineStart+1, '\n')){
      printf("%s\n", lineStart);  
   }
  }
}
```

The above stated code is supposed to search for a word in a file `(.txt)` and if found it should print `"found"` and print the line it was found in. For example, if searched for a word `"Brick"` in the file, and if found in a sentence like `"The house is made of red bricks"`, then it prints the whole sentence as the output i.e `"The house is made of the red bricks"`.

I am having trouble printing the line containing the search word. I am trying to use pointer to move to the start of the current line and then navigate incrementally but I am kinda stuck in how to make the pointer stop at the end of the line and just print up till that point.

Comment: move the `free`  to where you do not need it any more eg. at the end

Comment: @Hi-Angel well, you can. :-) `c99` onwards.

Comment: @Hi-Angel IMHO, you can remove the comment. It's misleading, somehow. Hope you understand. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with your code is, you call `free(bytes);` inside your code and after that, you continue to use `bytes`. This invokes [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also, i'll suggest

1. change your `scanf()` instruction

   ```
   scanf("%s", file_name);
   ```

   and

   ```
   scanf("%s", search);
   ```

   to

   ```
   scanf("99%s", file_name);
   ```

   and

   ```
   scanf("9%s", search);
   ```

   to avoid the risk of buffer overflow.
2. Always check for the success of `fopen()` before using the returned pointer.

However, from the logical point, i'll suggest you

1. Read a *whole* line by line from the file using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)
2. Search for the particular word using [`strstr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr).
3. If found, print the whole line, otherwise, continue to step 1 until `fgets()` return NULL.

Notes:

1. the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.
2. Always initialize *all* local variables.

Comment: in 3. how do i print the whole line?

Comment: @diplodocus well, the input buffer supplied in `fgets()` will contain the whole line. However, you may need to take care of the trailinh _newline_ yourself.

Comment: but what if the word is in the middle of the sentence? in that case fgets() wouldnt proceed further to the end of the line, would it?

Comment: @diplodocus um, `fgets()` reads the whole line, until `\n` or `EOF`. please check the man page in the link I provided.